# Придаточное времени или условия?

Tags: синтаксис

*В этом городе нельзя скрыть болезнь, **если докторская повозка стоит у твоего дома.***

Помогите пожалуйста, я запуталась: *когда нельзя скрыть болезнь?* или *при каком условии нельзя скрыть болезнь?*

Comment: Даже если было бы "когда докторская повозка", то всё равно - условия, мне кажется.  Значение - "при условии, что". Хотя, конечно, в строгом смысле, "когда" - временной союз.  http://lik-bez.com/board/morfologija/sojuz/40

Comment: Иными словами, можно понимать по-разному, но "если" - условно подчинительный, а "когда" - временно подчинительный.

Comment: ... ufffffiiiii дорогие моиии, не знаю, как решиться... замечу, что в оригинале это предложение на 100% временное...

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, здесь всё-таки придаточное временное, поскольку здесь говорится о том, что в этом городе нельзя скрыть болезнь (когда?).

Answer (score 1):

В этом городе нельзя скрыть болезнь, если докторская повозка стоит у твоего дома.

**СПП с придаточным условия, можно задать вопрос "при каком условии?"**.

Совместно с союзом ЕСЛИ можно использовать предложный оборот условной семантики:

В этом городе нельзя скрыть болезнь, в том случае если докторская повозка стоит у твоего дома.

Временной союз КОГДА может иметь значение условия: В этом городе нельзя скрыть болезнь, когда докторская повозка стоит у твоего дома.